# eBay API: how to use outputSelector in HTTP get request

Tags: http, get, request, ebay-api

I'm using URLs like this in my application

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1
?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced
&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
&SECURITY-APPNAME=MYAPPID
&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML
&REST-PAYLOAD&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-IT
&categoryId=CATEGORYID
&descriptionSearch=true
&keywords=KEYWORDS
```

I get the XML response, but I need more fields using [outputSelector](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#outputSelector).

But I don't understand how to use it in my request.

I tried to add a field like
`&outputSelector=searchResult.item.listingInfo.buyItNowAvailable`, but it doesn't add anything to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

**outputSelector** only has few fields, **itemFilter** workes instead.

&itemFilter.name=ListingType
&itemFilter.value=AuctionWithBIN

http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/extra/fndItmsAdvncdRqst.tmFltr.nm.html

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure to set your SERVICE-VERSION to be current. Usually it doesn't make a difference, but I've seen cases where it did. Change it to 1.12.0 and you're set. (Actually 1.11.0 may be better -- sometimes when it's TOO new there are quirks, believe it or not.)